# Time changes after toLocaleTimeString()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, time

I'm using a google sheets script, which on the click of a button will add values to two fields.
The first will contain the date, the second the time.
For this, I use this piece of code:

```
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  var time = timestamp.toLocaleTimeString('nl-BE');
```

Now, the issue is that the time is off by 6 hours.
The timestamp value does contain the correct time, the date variable gets the correct date, but the time seems to differ 6 hours after the 'toLocaleTimeString() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Utilities.formatDate()` for time as well, like this:

```js
  const timezone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(); // or 'GMT+1'
  const timestamp = new Date();
  const dateString = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, timezone, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  const timeString = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, timezone, 'HH:mm:ss');
  console.log(`date and time in ${timezone}: ${dateString} ${timeString}`);
```